# SQL Server Spatial Enable Spatial column and Analysis

Tags: sql-server-spatial

I have:

- a table called `ABC` with columns `(ID, County_Name, Lat, Long)` in SQL
  server pre-filled with the values under its respective columns,
  except for County_Name column which is currently null.
- an ArcGIS SDE feature class - called `US_County` with columns `(id,
  County_Name, Shape)`.

I am trying is call the SQL Server Spatial native STintersects() to get the county name from the US_County feature into my other non-spatial ABC table.  But I can't seem to get it working.

First I add in the Shape column to the ABC table like so:

```
ALTER TABLE ABC 
ADD Shape AS geometry::Point(Long,Lat,4326);
```

Then I do the STIntersects() like so:

```
UPDATE ABC 
SET County_Name = a.County_Name
FROM ABC c
JOIN US_County a
ON c.Shape.STIntersects(a.shape) =1;
```

Was wondering if the above SQL statements is correct?

Comment: You had a tag for the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst but make no mention of using it in your question body and so I have removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries looks fine, it looks to me that maybe your layers are not in the same SRID. Double check that.

> This method always returns null if the spatial reference IDs (SRIDs) of the geometry instances do not match.

[docs microsoft STIntersects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stintersects-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to be correct.  Before I have the polygon feature class with SRID of 3857.  So the two SRIDs is incorrect, was able to get it working by re-projecting the polygon feature class to SRID 4326.  Seems like MS SQL server does not have SRID 3857 under sys.spatial_reference_systems ?